# Is there an online ressource where i can download the gnucash sql model?

Tags: sql

It seems that the gnucash sql model is interleaved in the gnucash source code (and created by gnucash upon startup).

Do you know an url where I can download the dump of this sql model..in sql ?

Comment: Have you tried installing it, then creating a structural dump of of the created database?

Comment: yes i did just that and it answers my raw question. Zsolt's answer looks more like what i was looking for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a relatively [old schema](http://lists.gnucash.org/pipermail/gnucash-devel/2009-June/025712.html). But Gnucash [is not a DB application](http://lists.gnucash.org/pipermail/gnucash-devel/2009-June/025716.html).

But here are [some more recent docs](http://wiki.gnucash.org/wiki/SQL). And they have a nice diagramm as well ([link to larger version](http://cloud.github.com/downloads/jralls/gnucash/gnucash_erd.png)):

[image]